# Custom control - Property to add element to a binded DataSource

Tags: c#, user-controls

I have a question about a user control I am creating.

The user control is only a ComboBox (with personal settings), with a datasource from a list from a database.

This list is very simple, it’s a list of vehicule type.

Currently, my database looks like this :

```
Id_Vehicule_Type  Type     Description
1                 Car      Car description
2                 Truck    Truck description
3                 SUV      SUV description
```

I can link my data to my user control, there’s no problem with that.

What I want is an option (property) to add or remove an “All” field.

If I create a new vehicule, I would like to be able to choose between Car/Truck/SUV.

If I search for a vehicule, I would like to be able to choose between Car/Truck/SUV/All. All will search for any vehicule type.

I already add a property to my user control, but for the moment, I retrieve the list from my database in the «Set» section of my property. It check if the _IncludeAll is true, then add a new item in the list before binding it, but I don’t find this really « well-made ».

```
List<VehiculeType> vehiculeTypes = Database.GetAllVehiculeType();

if (this._IncludeAll)
{
    vehiculeTypes.Add(new VehiculeType(-1, "(All)"));
    this.cbVehiculeTypes1.SelectedValue = -1;
}
```

I have no problem retrieving the id / type / description from my user control. I only can’t figure out how to manage this « option ».

Thank you and have a nice day.

Comment: Why not add it to the database with a code of 0 and then based on a simple bool property you could include or exclude it from the datasource using a RowFilter.  Note that there is a difference between a custom control and a User Control

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Nicolas! The issue might be that you are adding it too late. Maybe try adding it in the InitializeComponent method. Another option might be  to make accept a includeAll parameter in your GetAllVehiculeType method, that would bring it back before you bind it to the control